# Searching mathematical algorithm for vector calculation

Tags: math, rotation, transform

I have given directions of 3D Objects like this:

Direction1:

X-Vector:

X_X: 1

X_Y: 0

X_Z: 0

Y-Vector:

Y_X: 0

Y_Y: 1

Y_Z: 0

Z-Vector:

Z_X: 0

Z_Y: 0

Z_Z: 1

Direction2:

X-Vector:

X_X: 0

X_Y: 0

X_Z: 1

Y-Vector:

Y_X: 0

Y_Y: -1

Y_Z: 0

Z-Vector:

Z_X: 1

Z_Y: 0

Z_Z: 0

That looks like this (Direction1 on the left, Direction2 on the right):

[image]

I have to filter out the information about the rotation from direction1 to direction2 now.
There are algorithms f.e. which calculates the rotation of vector1 to vector 2, but here i have 3 vectors and i don't know, how i can calculate the euler rotation angle here.

I thought about summarizing the 3 Vectors to 1, f.e. picture 1 would be (1,1,1) and pic2 would be (1,-1,1), but the problem here is that the information, which axe points in which direction gets lost.
Has somebody an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you want to find affine transformation that transforms one triplet of non-coplanar vectors into another triplet.
Make matrices **A** and **B** and unknown rotation matrix **M**.
Here column vector like `x1 y1 z1` is your `X_X   X_Y   X_Z` and so on.

```
 M * A = B

    |x1 x2 x3 0|     |x1` x2` x3` 0|
M * |y1 y2 y3 0| =   |y1` y2` y3` 0|
    |z1 z2 z3 0|     |z1` z2` z3` 0| 
    |1  1  1  1|     |1   1   1   1|
```

find inverse matrix **InvA** for the **A** and multiply both sides by **IA**

```
M * A * InvA = B * InvA
M * |1 |= B * InvA
M = B * InvA
```

Now you have matrix **M** needed to transform vectors.

Rotation about 5,0,0

```
      |1 0 0 -5|        |1 0 0 5|
M' =  |0 1 0  0| * M *  |0 1 0 0|
      |0 0 1  0|        |0 0 1 0|
      |0 0 0  1|        |0 0 0 1|
```

Comment: So by mutliplying the output matrix with the inverse input matrix i get my "transform-matrix", correct? I have got this function in my program: .setRotationFromMatrix ( m : Matrix4 ) : null
m -- rotate the quaternion by the rotation component of the matrix.

Will this work if m is the M calculated by B*InvA?

Comment: For general 4x4 matrix 4x4 you need to extend composed ones - I'll correct them. I doubt about quaternion - quaternion itself describes rotation (quaternion approach is alternative to rotation matrix). Perhaps `setRotationFromMatrix` does not rotate but creates quaternion with similar rotation as matrix.

Comment: I will program your solution and hopefully it will work. Thank you. I will write here if it worked or i need more of your help. I would love it if you could help me again if i don't know further

Comment: Edit: I will try it with this function:
R.extractRotation ( m : Matrix4 ) : this
Extracts the rotation component of the supplied matrix m into this matrix's rotation component. Do i have to multiply the Matrix of my Object with this extractRotation output? M*R?

Comment: I hoped that you can use M itself to make rotation

Comment: You helped me very well, can you help me with another little problem? I don't want to rotate the object in it center with the matrix, i want to rotate it in another pivot point. Is there some way to directly input this point in the matrix? f.e. instead of (0,0,0) in point (5,0,0).. When i apply the Matrix M to my object it rotates always around its center

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You have to add two matrices in multiplication chain - the first makes shift by -5,0,0, then goes rotation, and the last matrix makes backward shift 5,0,0

Comment: Oh wow, can you please make an example above? It would help me massively ,because it doesn't seem like i can code that myself..

Comment: Look at translation matrix [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry))

Comment: So i multiply with this:
|1 0 0 5|     
|0 1 0 0|  
|0 0 1 0|  
|0  0  0  1|  
       
then with M and then with the first one, just -5 instead of 5? sry i cant format the comment somehow.. the last row of zeros (except the last 1 because its part of the diagonal) is correct like this?

Comment: I added to the post